# Calculating Kafka lag in spark structured streaming application

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to calculate Kafka lag on my spark structured streaming application.

I can get the current processed offset from my Kafka metadata which comes along with actual data.

Is there a way through which we can get the latest offsets of all partitions in a Kafka topic programmatically from spark interface ?

Can I use Apache Kafka admin classes or Kafka interfaces to get the latest offset information for each batch in my spark app ?

Comment: In the past i have leveraged burrow and cmak.
But you have more options now https://www.entechlog.com/blog/kafka/monitoring-kafka-consumer-lag/
https://www.lightbend.com/blog/monitor-kafka-consumer-group-latency-with-kafka-lag-exporter

Comment: Is there a way to get the latest offsets per partition from spark streaming code programmatically ?